# Problem in Converting a binary tree to a threaded binary tree

Tags: c#, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I want to convert a binary tree to threaded binary tree.
this is my algorithm and code to convert.
but i get the error "Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.
"

```
   public void ConvertToTBT(Node r, int[] inorder)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inorder.Length; i++)
        {
            Node temp = Search(r, inorder[i]);

            if (i <= inorder.Length - 2)
                if (temp.rightChild == null)
                {
                    temp.rightChild = Search(r, inorder[i + 1]);
                    temp.is_right_thread = true;
                }
            if (i != 0)
                if (temp.leftChild == null)
                {
                    temp.leftChild = Search(r, inorder[i - 1]);
                    temp.is_left_thread = true;
                }

        }
    }
```

and this is the search method(that finds a node and return that) i found here and use in my code

```
public Node Search(Node root, int data)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            if (root.data == data)
                return root;
            else
            {
                Node foundNode = Search(root.leftChild, data);
                if (foundNode == null)
                    foundNode = Search(root.rightChild, data);
                return foundNode;
            }
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

where do i make mistake?!

if you have a better idea for converting a BT to TBT , So please help me!

NOTE that my tree is a binary one NOT Binary search

also my biuldTree method

```
public Node BuildTree(int[] inorder, int[] preorder, int instart, int inend)
    {
        if (instart > inend)
            return null;
        if (preindex >= inorder.Length)
            return null;
        int pickedpre = preorder[preindex];
        preindex++;

        Node newnode = new Node(pickedpre);
        if (instart == inend)
            return newnode;

        for (int i = 0; i < inorder.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inorder[i] == pickedpre)
            {
                inindex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        newnode.leftChild = BuildTree(inorder, preorder, instart, inindex - 1);
        newnode.rightChild = BuildTree(inorder, preorder, inindex + 1, inend);

        root = newnode;
        return newnode;
    }
```

Comment: Where does the StackOverlow exception occur? In your Search or your BuildTree method?

Comment: @KlausGütter StackOverlow exception occur in my Search method.BuildTree is fine.the problem is with either Search or ConvertToTBT method. when i trace search method , for the third node to thread, it can not get outside the search method

Comment: @KlausGütter this is my project for Data Structure.i really got tired on this! i can explain my code if needed

Comment: Your Search method will Stack-overflow if your "tree" contains cycles, i.e. if a left_child or right_child references a node that has already been visited. You might add some additional code to your ConvertToTBT method to verify that this invariant is maintained.

Comment: Can you provide full code so I can run it and try to understand better what you try to accomplish?